# How to restrict fields in a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to run a query where I am supposed to find the sale amount and bill count of a specific product.  In my table I have the fields billID, description (which is the name of the product) and amount (which is the dollar amount sold).  My problem is that I have to find when a specific product was sold without another accompanying it.  For example: if I sell a double burger things like gravy and fries might appear in the same bill but they are not charged extra so they appear as 0.00 in the billID.  However, if the customer orders a single burger besides the double burger there will be two different items that are charged under the same billID.  I would like to know how to count only those bills that contain "double burger" in a billID and nothing else that is a different product that is chargeable.  I hope you can help me.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: you should add what you would like your results to look like and what flavor of SQL you are running

Comment: It will also help if you shows us a few rows of samples data and some attempt you have made yourself as a starting point. And specifying your RDBMS is often helpful.

Comment: restriction occurs in your where clause, but in this case you may want to also have an IF statement. Post your SQL flavor

Comment: SQL is an exercise in set logic (in most cases) Step 1) get all billIDs with your double Burger.  Step 2) exclude all BillIDs from teh first set in the set of all records excluding double burger.

Comment: Hi.  I am using MS SQL.  So far I have attempted queries like this:

Comment: Hi.  I am using a data warehouse in MS SQL.  So far I have attempted queries like this: select count(billid) as bills, description, sum(amount) from dbo.FactSales where companyid = 4 and datekey = 20140422 and description = 'double burger' group by description, amount, billid.   This works but it will count billids that have other chargeable items in it such as single burgers and so.  My aim is to get the bill count of bills where only a double burger has been charged and nothing else.  That is the tricky part for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below Basically says return all BIllIDs that by themselves are 'double burger' OR have multiple entries on the same bill but all of those entries are for $0 charge.

Any records where the sale amount is <> 0 will result but have a 'double burger' and a non double burger entry in a value in T2.BillId and those will be excluded.

```
SELECT T1.BillID
FROM TABLE T1
LEFT JOIN table2 T2
  on T1.BillID = T2.BillId 
  and T1.Description = 'double burger'
  and t2.descirption <> 'double burger'
  and t1.description <> t2.description
  AND t2.SaleAmount <> 0
 Where T2.BillID is null
```

So from a set concept:

- return all the 'double burgers' set.
- Return all the bills that have double burgers and non-double burgers with a non-double burger sale amount > 0
- now exclude those billID's that have a non- double burger sale amount > 0 from the original set.

Comment: Hi xQbert.  It did not work for me.  My problem is that there might be several items in the same billid.  Some of them are charged like another burger or extra fries but I am trying to get only those bills that the only thing that they charged was the double burger even if there are other things in the bill as long as they are not charged.  In other words things gravy that the charge amount is 0.00.  Thanks.

Comment: added and t2.saleamount <> 0  This way all 0 amounts will be excluded from the join.  Thereby anything that is <> double burger will be included in the joined results; and then subsequently excluded by the check t2.billID is null

Comment: It is returning all the data actually.